# Setting the working directory for picture insert in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Every once in while I am using PowerPoint 2007 and always I add some figures to my slides using Insert and then select Picture.

What botters me here, that it initially opens the Pictures library to select a picture from. this is default behavior. When I restart PowerPoint, this is again the default location.

Can I change this default behavior of PowerPoint such, that the directory where the presentation is stored, is the folder that is opened when inserting a picture?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Current Folder using the environment variable %CD%.

WARNING: Using Registry Editor incorrectly can cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system.  I cannot be held responsible for the problems resulting from the incorrect use of Registry Editor. Use Registry Editor at your own risk.

1. Quit all open Windows applications. On the Windows Start menu, click Run.
2. In the Open box, type Regedit, and click OK.
3. Expand the HKEY_CURRENT_USER sub tree until you see the following folder:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER
   \Software
       \Microsoft
           \Windows
               \CurrentVersion
                   \Explorer
                       \User Shell Folders
4. Select the "User Shell Folders" folder.
5. Create a new string value, by selecting Edit|New|String value from the rename it to "My Pictures" (without the quotes). After renaming it, double click it & set it's value data to the path that you want it to default too; e.g. "C:\Images\Jpegs" . Or %CD% for current folder. 
   Note: If "My Pictures" string value already exists merely change it's value data.
6. Quit the Registry Editor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change it. It will require you to edit the registry to make this change. Here are the step by step instructions found at [OfficeTips](http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00039.htm).

> WARNING: Using Registry Editor incorrectly can cause serious problems
>   that may require you to reinstall your operating system.  I cannot be
>   held responsible for the problems resulting from the incorrect use of
>   Registry Editor. Use Registry Editor at your own risk.
>
> 1. Quit all open Windows applications. On the Windows Start menu, click Run.
> 2. In the Open box, type Regedit, and click OK.
> 3. Expand the HKEY_CURRENT_USER sub tree until you see the following folder:
>
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER
>          \Software
>              \Microsoft
>                  \Windows
>                      \CurrentVersion
>                          \Explorer
>                              \User Shell Folders
> 4. Select the "User Shell Folders" folder.
> 5. Create a new string value, by selecting Edit|New|String value from the rename it to "My Pictures" (without the quotes). After renaming
>      it, double click it & set it's value data to the path that you want it
>      to default too; e.g. "C:\Images\Jpegs". **Note:** If "My Pictures" string value already exists merely change it's value data.
> 6. Quit the Registry Editor.

Comment: I hoped for an easier solution. Besides, this will change the default folder to a different default as far as I can tell. Am I right? However, I would like the folder to be dynamically picked, based on the directory where the presentation is saved.

Comment: Are you willing to do something in VBA?

Comment: Actually, no :)

Comment: OK. Thanks for being honest. Sorry. There doesn't appear to be an easy way to do what you asked.

Comment: What would the VBA or a macro way be to do thuis?