# Insert a picture (from file) in Word: how to open current folder by default?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

Is there a way to configure MS Word (2007) to open the *current* folder (i.e., where the active document is located) by default, and not a single application-wide default folder (as configured under options, e.g. 'My Pictures')?

Alternatively, if this can not be done, is there an easy way to quickly go the current folder in the 'Insert Picture' dialog box?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/462291/setting-the-working-directory-for-picture-insert-in-powerpoint).

Comment: @Scoot: Ah, indeed. There doesn't seem to be an answer to that question though.

Comment: @Rabarberski: You can promote it by giving it a bounty.